# How would create define an element in an XSD which has attributes and has restrictions

Tags: xml, xsd

How to set enumeration restrictions for a complex type restriction??

i-e I want to define an element in the XSD such that it can have attributes and has restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a complex type with simple content that can extend a simple type with the enumeration restrictions that you want adding additional attributes. See a working example below:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:simpleType name="restrictedType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string"> 
            <xs:enumeration value="v1"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="v2"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:complexType name="testType">
      <xs:simpleContent>
          <xs:extension base="restrictedType">
              <xs:attribute name="att"/>
          </xs:extension>
      </xs:simpleContent>          
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="test" type="testType"/>
</xs:schema>
```

a valid instance will be

```
<test att="x">v1</test>
```

Best Regards,
George